# Is it safe to use only named modules in RequireJS instead of using the name/folder algorithm?

Tags: javascript, jquery, js-amd

I'm converting an existing project to RequireJS and I'm doing it in steps.

Currently I'm only attempting to conditionally load jQuery 1 or 2 depending on some Modernizr Tests...

However the namespacing portion of the script is located in a template file...  while the scripts are currently split up between a batch of files that gets concatenated and minified later and some inline scripts strewn throughout the template files...  I hate to just start moving code around and would like to keep most of it in place while I try to get the conditional loading running..  so my question is:

How important is it to adhere to the name-to-file-path lookup algorithm rules in RequireJS?

It says to never define more than one module per file, but I'm unsure why this is.

Comment: It read "[do not] define more than one module per [source] file [that is distributed as an independent resource]". This is because it throws off the automatic resolution and generation/optimization tooling. If not wanting to scatter around the 'pkg/name' code everyone then aliases can be established in the configuration. A downside is this slightly increases the chance of a global name collision.

Comment: What should I use in the config to do this?

Comment: Both the [paths and map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19216580/requirejs-paths-vs-map) options can be used here; they work differently, however.