# Knockout and jquery-ui\sortable Requirejs Configuration using CDN

Tags: jquery-ui, knockout.js, requirejs, cdn

I'm trying to load a lot of our JS dependencies using requirejs.  We are having an issue with the dependency that KnockoutSortable has on jquery-ui\sortable.

I can not get sortable.js to come from the cdn download of jquery-ui it is satisfying it's dependency by downloading from the copy within my site.  I have tried to shim

```
'knockoutSortable' : {
    deps: ['jqueryUi']
},
```

but that has not forced Knockout to use the CDN downloaded version of jquery-ui

Our configuration is as follows:

```
var require = {
baseUrl: '/Scripts',
paths: {
    jquery: ['//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min', 'lib/jquery-1.9.1.min'],
    jqueryUi: ['//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min', 'lib/jquery-ui-1.11.3.min'],        
    knockout: ['//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-min','lib/knockout-3.3.0.min'],
    knockoutMapping: ['//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min','lib/knockout.mapping-latest.min'],
    knockoutValidation: ['//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout-validation/2.0.2/knockout.validation.min','lib/knockout.validation.min'],
    knockoutPostBox: ['//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout-postbox/0.5.1/knockout-postbox.min', 'lib/knockout-postbox.min'],
    knockoutSortable: ['//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout-sortable/0.11.0/knockout-sortable.min','lib/knockout-sortable.min'],
    ...
shim: {
    'jquery': {
        exports: '$'
    },
    'knockoutSortable' : {
    deps: ['jqueryUi']
},...
```

Comment: Since jquery-ui and knockout both AMD compatible you can't use a shim configuration you need to use a map config.  See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19216580/requirejs-paths-vs-map)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since jquery-ui and knockout both AMD compatible you can't use a shim configuration you need to use a map config instead to map jquery-ui modules back to the jqueryUi path.

See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19216580/requirejs-paths-vs-map)

We solved this by adding this map configuration to the require.config

```
map : {
    '*': {
        'jquery-ui/core': 'jqueryUi',
        'jquery-ui/sortable': 'jqueryUi',
        'jquery-ui/draggable': 'jqueryUi',
        'jquery-ui/mouse': 'jqueryUi',
        'jquery-ui/widget': 'jqueryUi'
    }
}
```